# Create crone job in sql server management studio 2014

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a sql query/stored procedure which  automatically executes at the end of each month. I am unable to find 'Sql Server Agent' in Sql Server Management Studio 2014.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Comment: Are you using sql server express edition, sql standard editon, sql server enterprise edition, sql server developer edition or something else?

Comment: @Techno This is the version of the tool not the server. Can you do a `SELECT @@VERSION` on a query window in management studio and tell us what it returns?

Comment: @P. Salmon:I am using express edition

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos : It returns

Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP1-GDR) (KB3194720) - 12.0.4232.0 (X64) 
 Sep 23 2016 18:45:14 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: )

Comment: You could upgrade to developer edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run SELECT @@VERSION and identify the SQL Server version you are using.

SQL Agent is not available in Express edition.

If you are using Standard/Enterprise/Developer edition, then please check your permissions. Your login should be added to SQLAgentUserRole or SQLAgentReaderRole or SQLAgentOperatorRole MSDB database roles.

Comment: Is there any other way to create crone job in sql server express edition?

Comment: You can't create SQL agent jobs in Express edition, however you can create required scripts in .SQL files and use windows Task scheduler to execute them. Use SQLCMD utility to run the scripts. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility